# XHTML element audio not allowed as child of SVG element

Tags: audio, svg

I'm creating an interactive infographic using SVG, audio and some JavaScript.

I can validate the document by direct input using the [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/), however, I get this error when trying to validate via URI or file upload:

> XHTML element audio not allowed as child of SVG element

What am I missing? I understand `<audio>` is not standard SVG (ditto for the use of `data-*` attributes actually). What I don't understand is why the namespace declarations in the SVG tag wouldn't be sufficient.

Here is a minimum case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<svg    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    viewBox="0 0 640 640">

<defs>
    <audio id="consonant_pig_audio" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><source type="audio/mpeg" src="https://bilingueanglais.com/tmp/ipa-infographic-preview-v1/audio/IPA-PIG.mp3"/></audio>
</defs>


<title>SVG with audio</title>

<rect class="trigger" width="640" height="640" data-target="consonant_pig" />


<script><![CDATA[
/** Shortcut to querySelector **/
function $(sel) { return document.querySelector(sel); }
function $all(sel) { return document.querySelectorAll(sel); }

/** Execute when the SVG is ready **/
(function() {

    $all( '.trigger' ).forEach( function( element ) {
        element.addEventListener( 'click', function() {

            var audio = $( '#' + this.getAttribute('data-target') + '_audio' );
            if ( audio !== null ) {
                try { audio.currentTime=0; } catch(e) {} audio.play();
            }


        }, false );
    });

})();
]]></script>

</svg>
```

Comment: The validator is old, data- attributes and audio are new (part of the in-progress SVG 2 specification).

Comment: @RobertLongson Would that make my SVG valid under SVG 1.1 ?

Comment: In SVG 1.1 all elements in a non-SVG namespace should strictly be children of foreignObject. In practice this has never actually been necessary for the audio tag I think.

Answer (score 0):

As per Robert Longson's comment, I merely used `<foreignObject>` to produce 100% valid SVG -- note that its content needs to be wrapped in a `<body>` to be valid.

(I also got rid of data-attribute as I wanted the code to fully validate, even though they do work in the browsers in practice and are part of the SVG2 spec.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    viewBox="0 0 640 640">

<defs>
    <foreignObject width="0" height="0" requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <audio id="consonant_pig_audio" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><source type="audio/mpeg" src="https://bilingueanglais.com/tmp/ipa-infographic-preview-v1/audio/IPA-PIG.mp3"/></audio>
        </body>
    </foreignObject>
</defs>

<title>SVG with audio</title>

<rect class="trigger" width="640" height="640">
    <metadata>consonant_pig</metadata>
</rect>

<script><![CDATA[
/** Shortcut to querySelector **/
function $(sel) { return document.querySelector(sel); }
function $all(sel) { return document.querySelectorAll(sel); }

/** Execute when the SVG is ready **/
(function() {

    $all( '.trigger' ).forEach( function( element ) {
        element.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
            //console.log( this.querySelector( 'metadata' ).textContent );
            var audio = $( '#' + this.querySelector( 'metadata' ).textContent + '_audio' );
            if ( audio !== null ) {
                try { audio.currentTime=0; } catch(e) {} audio.play();
            }


        }, false );
    });

})();
]]></script>

</svg>
```

For the `data-*`-like attributes, another approach that validates would have been to rely on the `id` attribute or on `<desc>` elements. (If multiple `data-*`-like attributes are required on a single element, `<metadata>` ceases to be an option because it does not support the `class` attribute, while `<desc>` does.)